# How to update values in printed output only in C?

Tags: c

I want to print a line:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   printf("this is iteration number %d\n", i);
```

From this I will get output as:

this is iteration number 0

this is iteration number 1

...

But I want that only one line is printed and the value changes.
That is I want to overwrite each line.

Now if I print some another line (lets call it line2) but I need to overwrite the previous line without affecting the line2.

Comment: What platform are you on? Is it only a single line and the last line displayed you wish to update?

Comment: Do you mean you want each line to overwrite the previous one?

Comment: Yes i want each line to overwrite previous one

Comment: besides using '\r' you could also use the ANSI escape sequence similar to: `0x1b[100D` to move the cursor to the beginning of the current line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) `\r` to return the cursor to the front of the line and then overwrite it in the next iteration:

```
int n = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\rThis is iteration number %d", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: You should add a call to `fflush(stdout);` so that the output doesn't get stuck in the buffer, because the only character that forces a flush is `\n` (usually), and now it isn't there anymore.

Comment: this is rather IFFY as the output will not be displayed until a output buffer overflow or the program ends

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I updated the script as you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Not the most refined solution, but you can use a "carriage return" `\r` and flush `stdout` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("\rValue of i is: %d", i);
      fflush(stdout);
      sleep(1);
  }
}
```